# How to apply regexp to the cell array in Matlab?

Tags: regex, matlab, cell-array

I'm having the cell array *res* with cells 3x2, each of them containing a string. I want to apply **regexp** to each cell and it should look like that:

```
fin = cellfun(@regexp(res, '\.', 'split'),res,'UniformOutput',false)
```

however it doesn't do the job. Anyone knows how it can be combined properly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were on the right track, but the syntax of your anonymous function is wrong. Try this:

```
fin = cellfun(@(x)regexp(x, '\.', 'split'), res, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Comment: In newer MATLAB versions, `regexp` can handle a cell array as input on its own. So no real need for a cellfun any more.

Comment: @Xerusial Appreciate the comment, and good to know! (as I haven't touched MATLAB for a while). But still, the original question includes `cellfun`...

Answer (score 0):

And if you have a cell "res", which consists of numeric and strings and would like to replace "a" with "b" in every char of "res", then you should use the following:

```
idx_isNumeric = @(x) any(isnumeric(x));                     
idx_isNumeric2 = cellfun(idx_isNumeric, res);  
res( ~idx_isNumeric2 ) = regexprep( res( ~idx_isNumeric2 ), 'a', 'b');
```

Hope it helps;)